# how to eliminate padding and/or margin between legend and form elements

Tags: slds, form, fieldsets

I am creating a compound form using SLDS and I want to create a fieldset where the legend and fields align horizontally. However, as can be seen in the pic below, [image: Pic of the fieldset] the legend and the fields are not aligned as there is some padding and/or margin above the fields and I have tried to eliminate it without success. Here is my truncated code.

```
<div class="slds-form__row">
   <div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem"></div>
       <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound slds-form-element_horizontal slds-m-vertical_none slds-p-vertical_none">
          <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label slds-m-vertical_none slds-p-vertical_none"><abbr class="slds-required" title="required">* </abbr>Discount Pricing Condition</legend>
              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                         <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                             <div class="slds-form-element">
                                  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                     <lightning:select>
                                     </lightning:select>
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <lightning:select>
                                </lightning:select>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </fieldset>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can horizontally align the legend with the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean align vertically? (The legend and the two select fields all in one row?) If so, I think you will want to include the legend in the grid that you are creating. Example:

```
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">

    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-form-element__row slds-m-around_none">
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Location</legend>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <select class="slds-select">
                            <option>Some text here</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <select class="slds-select">
                            <option>Some text here</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Link to a playground: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground